# For Loop Variables In Batch Files: Unexpected Results

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, registry, uninstallation

I'm attempting to use a batch file to uninstall any instances of a certain program by pulling the UninstallString from the registry. I've had success with this before, but not sure what I'm missing here.

This is the code in question:

```
REM Loop thru Uninstall keys
ECHO Checking installed programs list for myAPP.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall') DO (
    REM For each uninstall key, look for the DisplayName to match our application.
    FOR /F "tokens=3" %%B IN ('reg query "%%A" /v DisplayName') DO (
        REM If it's our application, uninstall it.
        IF "%%B" == "myAPP" (
            ECHO Found %%B at %%A
            FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('reg query "%%A" /v UninstallString') DO (
                ECHO Uninstalling instance.
                ECHO %%C %%D
                start /wait %%C %%D
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The `ECHO %%C %%D` statement works as expected, but the `start /wait %%C %%D` line does not.

Output before `start`:

```
Checking installed programs list for myAPP
Found myAPP at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\1139844978.www.myDOMAIN.local
Uninstalling instance.
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.20125.0\Silverlight.Configuration.exe -uninstallApp 1139844978.www.myDOMAIN.local
```

But the `start` command gives me an error saying could not find "C:\Program" which tells me it's not using the entire UninstallString as I thought it would, based on the results from the `Echo` right before it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Update:

Got it working. For some reason the `FOR` loop was splitting between C:\Program and the rest of the string, which I don't understand since there are other spaces in the rest of that path.

Anyhow, I was able to use another `FOR` loop to split up the string and separate the program `START` was calling from the arguments passed.

I don't think this is an ideal solution, as it only happens to work because of the way this particular *UninstallString* is formatted, but it works.

Here's the updated code:

```
:isInstalled
REM Loop thru Uninstall keys
ECHO Checking if already installed.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall') DO (
    REM For each uninstall key, look for the DisplayName to match our application.
    FOR /F "tokens=3" %%B IN ('reg query "%%A" /v DisplayName') DO (
        REM If it's our application, uninstall it.
        IF "%%B" == "myAPP" (
            ECHO Found %%B at %%A
            FOR /F "tokens=3*" %%C IN ('reg query "%%A" /v UninstallString') DO (
               ECHO Uninstalling instance.
               FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%E IN ('ECHO %%~C %%~D') DO (         
                   START /wait "" "%%E" -%%F
               )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This leaps around waving a flag while shouting "put quote marks around your parameters" to me ...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 start /wait "" "%%~C" "%%~D"
```

Comment: I tried that, and also `start /wait "" "%%C %%D"` which is now throwing up an error: `Windows cannot find 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.201.25.0\Silverlight.Configuration.exe -uninstallApp 1139844978.www.myDOMAIN.local'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`

Comment: As a side note, I *did* verify this file exists. It has to be something goofy with how `start.exe` is interpreting things, as if the entire string is the file, and not distinguishing the arguments. I'm thinking I may need to delimit and separate the arguments inside another `FOR` loop to get it to work. I wish I could just say, "see that value in UninstallString? Run it."

Comment: you can try this: `start /wait "" "%%~C" %%D` , no double quotes around `%%D` .

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue, and it appears to be related to the parentheses in the environment variable.  i.e. C:\Program Files**(**x86**)**.  I wish I had a more elegant solution, but our solution is very similar to yours.

Thanks